# Grails unit-test url-mapping for '/$controller'

Tags: unit-testing, grails, url-mapping

how to do unit-test url-mappings in grails for test '/$controller' ?

```
 "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
       constraints {
           // apply constraints here
       }
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Grails has built in capabilities for this (if you are using grails 2.x). http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingURLMappings

Comment: Latest version of the docs now refers to Grails 3, and has nothing about unit testing url mappings. See instead: http://docs.grails.org/2.4.5/guide/testing.html#unitTestingURLMappings